# Collection asset not found

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, image, folium

I am using this code

```
BANDS=['B1', 'B2', 'B3','B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7']
area = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1GxT2Q22KIGDjLFY1J11IX8lTAQPIoNyvBsG2fX0')
collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR').filterBounds(area).filterDate('2019-10-15', '2020-02-17')\
.select(BANDS).median().clip(area)
map=folium.Map(location=([-10.892409779059864,-46.763759689976126]),zoom_start=10)
map.addLayer(collection.select(['B7','B5','B4']),{'min':0,'max':0.5,'gamma':0.7})
map
```

But i got this error assent is not found

```
Collection.loadTable: Collection asset 'ft:1GxT2Q22KIGDjLFY1J11IX8lTAQPIoNyvBsG2fX0' not found.
```

Comment: The error would suggest that 'ft:1GxT2Q22KIGDjLFY1J11IX8lTAQPIoNyvBsG2fX0' does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

`ee.FeatureCollection('ft:*')` tries to load a fusion table, and Fusion tables are shut down, and all data has been deleted.

See [FAQ: Google Fusion Tables](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/9551050).